# Sort multidimensional arrays recursively after setting up child-parent realtions

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a database structure like this:

```
ID   name         sort   parent
1    item1        1      0
2    subitem1     2      1
3    subsubitem1  1      2
4    subitem2     1      1
```

I write the database into an array

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'item1' (length=5)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'subitem1' (length=8)
      'parent' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'subsubitem1' (length=11)
      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'subitem2' (length=8)
      'parent' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
```

and restructure that array to set up child-parent relations with this function:

```
function generateNavArray($arr, $parent = 0)
{
    $items = Array();
    foreach($arr as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] == $parent)
        {
            $item['child'] = isset($item['child']) ? $item['child'] : GenerateNavArray($arr, $item['id']);
            $items[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

and the generated array looks like this

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'item1' (length=5)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
      'child' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              'id' => string '2' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'subitem' (length=4)
              'parent' => string '1' (length=1)
              'sort' => string '2' (length=1)
              'child' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    array (size=5)
                      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
                      'name' => string 'subsubitem1' (length=11)
                      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
                      'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
                      'child' => 
                        array (size=0)
                          empty
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              'id' => string '3' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'subitem2' (length=8)
              'parent' => string '1' (length=1)
              'sort' => string '1' (length=1)
              'child' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
```

now i need to sort every dimension of the array by the sort value, (my "real array" has more subarrays then this one).
i played around with multisort but i can't seem to find the solution
any ideas?

Comment: Sort the array when it is 1 dimension before you build the multi-dimensional array. Even better if you are using a query, sort it there. Sort by `parent` then `sort`. When you build your multidimensional array, each child will be appended to the parent. If they are already in the correct order, they will end up in the same order.

Comment: omg you are right im so dump..... THX

Comment: Why don't you read in the data already sorted by the database engine? Do you need to resort the same data after one sort order has already been displayed?

Comment: posted an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array when it is 1 dimension before you build the multi-dimensional array. Even better if you are using a query, sort it there. Sort by parent then sort. When you build your multidimensional array, each child will be appended to the parent. If they are already in the correct order, they will end up in the same order.

Comment: I focused so much on the problem that i overlooked the easiest solution... thx man